# Updating a list in a JSONB Object SQL/SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71977609/sqlalchemy-adding-updating-jsonb-field-in-postgres/71978331?noredirect=1#comment127266059_71978331). Please what if you would like to perform a single update by appending it to the list of children in place, how would you go about it?

I would like a Python/SQLAlchemy solution if possible. Thanks

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Are you looking for a SQL solution (UPDATE) or a Python/SQLAlchemy solution?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am looking for both but preferably a Python/SQLAlchemy solution.